# React Form not updating state onChange

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to practice React forms, and I can't seem to solve this error. I've developed a multi-input form and I need the value to update the parent's state. When I start typing in the input field it triggers the Switch case default. I'm not sure if maybe I'm typing the 'handleChange' function wrong or if I should have a separate state for the state.data. Any advice would be much appreciated

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import Form from './Form';
import Results from './Results';

function App() {
    const [state, setState] = useState({
        data: 1,
        Name: '',
        Email: '',
        City: ''
    });

    const nextStep = () => {
        setState({
            data: state.data + 1
        });
  };

  const handleChange = e => {
        let field = e.target.name;
        let val = e.target.value;
        setState({ [field]: val });
    };

    switch (state.data) {
        case 1:
            return (
                <div className='App-container'>
                    <Form
                        button='Next'
                        nextStep={nextStep}
                        name='Name'
                        state={state.name}
                        handleChange={handleChange}
                    />
                </div>
            );
        case 2:
            return (
                <div className='App-container'>
                    <Form
                        button='Next'
                        nextStep={nextStep}
                        name='Email'
                        state={state.email}
                        handleChange={handleChange}
                    />
                </div>
            );
        case 3:
            return (
                <div className='App-container'>
                    <Form
                        button='Submit'
                        nextStep={nextStep}
                        name='City'
                        state={state.city}
                        handleChange={handleChange}
                    />
                </div>
            );
        case 4:
            return (
                <div className='App-container'>
                    <Results data={state} />
                </div>
            );
        default:
            return 'Error';
    }
}

export default App;

import React from 'react';

const Form = ({ button, nextStep, name, state, handleChange }) => {
    const handleSubmit = e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        nextStep();
    };

    return (
        <div className='Form-container'>
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                <input
                    type='text'
                    placeholder={name}
                    name={name}
                    value={state}
                    onChange={handleChange}
                />
                <input type='submit' value={button} />
            </form>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Form;


import React from 'react';

const Results = ({ data }) => {
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Info</h1>
            <p>{data.name}</p>
            <p>{data.email}</p>
            <p>{data.city}</p>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Results;
```

Comment: hooks setter does not merge state like class component setter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You losing state on `handleChange` while expecting it to merge with the current one, but it **is not how `useState` works** [in contradiction to `this.setState`](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-are-merged) in class components:

```
// Results new state: { data };
setState({ data: state.data + 1 });

// Instead update the copy of the state.
// Results new state: { data, Name, Email, City }
setState({ ...state, data: state.data + 1 });
```

Check [`useState` note in docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usestate):

> Note
>
> Unlike the setState method found in class components, useState does
> not automatically merge update objects. You can replicate this
> behavior by combining the function updater form with object spread
> syntax.
>
> Another option is useReducer,
> which is more suited for managing state objects that contain multiple
> sub-values.

Comment: Any idea why when submit the first form the value gets carried over to the input in the second and third form?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using a custom hook for form inputs.like follows

```
//useForm.js

const useForm = defaultValues => {
  const [values, setValues] = useState(defaultValues);
  const handleChange = ({ name, value }) => {
    setValues(prevState => ({ ...values, [name]: value }));
  };
  const reset = () => {
    setValues(null);
  };
  return [values, handleChange, reset];
};
```

inside component

```
 const [formValues, handleChange, resetForm] = useForm();

 return (
    <>
     <Input
       value={formValues.name}
        onChange: str => handleChange({ name: "name", value: str })
      />

     <Input
       value={formValues.email}
        onChange: str => handleChange({ name: "email", value: str })
      />
    </>
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to spared old state

```
  const handleChange = e => {
        let field = e.target.name;
        let val = e.target.value;
        setState({ ...state, [field]: val });
    };
```

this is `setState({ ...state, [field]: val });`