# Edit form that is pre-filled with API data - React

Tags: mysql, node.js, reactjs

I am building a form that is pre-populated by the results of an axios get request to a nodejs API that returns an array (stored in MySQL). I asked this question yesterday, implemented a solution that was provided and it worked. The next day I tested it thoroughly and it turns out that on submission only the edited fields were passed but not the values from the unedited fields.

I can get the data to map onto the form, but i cannot edit the form. The idea is for it to be an "edit user" form. I suspect the issue is in the onChange portion of the input field.

The form is accessed from a table that is also mapped with the results of a get request. Upon clicking the edit button, the userID from the table row is passed to the edit form through useNavigate and useLocation (I can add this portion of code if needed).

**Backend**

Here is the API controller that queries the MySQL database and then sends to the frontend:

```
export const edit = async (req, res) => {
  db.query(
    "SELECT * FROM userIndex WHERE userID = ?",
    [req.params.userID],
    (err, rows) => {
      if (!err) {
        res.send(rows);
      } else {
        console.log(err).res.send({ alert: err });
      }
    }
  );
};
```

Here's an example result of the query above:

```
[
    {
        "userID": 143,
        "firstName": "Kenan",
        "lastName": "Erasmus",
        "role": "student",
        "email": "kenan@gmail.com",
        "password": "$2b$12$v3s0D6cNkGwM3/IWXPdv..TRfRZLmDNuZBfrWlUCt4vKnyRi75jWe",
        "createdAt": "06/10/2022, 13:56:51",
        "updatedAt": "07/10/2022, 19:45:46",
        "lastLogin": null
    }
]
```

**Frontend**

Here is the portion of code that performs the request to the API:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const config = {
      headers: { "x-auth-token": token },
    };

    const fetchData = async () => {
      const results = await api.get("/users/edituser/" + userID, config);
      setRows(results.data);
      setFirstName(rows.firstName)
    };
    fetchData();
  }, [setRows, userID, token]);
```

State for "rows" (set on API response):

```
const [rows, setRows] = useState([]);
const [firstName, setFirstName] = useState("");
```

And finally, an example input field:

```
<input
 type="text"
 className="form-control"
 id="inputEmail4"
 placeholder="First Name"
 name="firstName"
 value={firstName}
 onChange={(e) => setFirstName(e.target.value)}
></input>
```

I have only included the "firstName" input as an example. In total, this form has about 6 fields.

I would greatly appreciate any assistance with this. Let me know if I can supply any more code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React Form not updating state onChange](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60943798/react-form-not-updating-state-onchange)

Comment: I'll implement and get back to you shortly @DeanVanGreunen

Comment: This implementation gives me "rows.map is not a function". So the state is empty instead of holding the API response data @DeanVanGreunen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a workaround that seems quite logical to me. I initialised new blank states for each of the input fields

```
const [firstName, setFirstName] = useState("");
```

Then mapped the form with "rows" and set each field value to its correspond state (as seen in the useEffect below)

Frontend useEffect:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const config = {
      headers: { "x-auth-token": token },
    };

    const fetchData = async () => {
      const results = await api.get("/users/edituser/" + userID, config);
      setRows(results.data);
      setFirstName(results.data[0].firstName);
      setLastName(results.data[0].lastName);
      setEmail(results.data[0].email);
      setPassword(results.data[0].password);
      setRole(results.data[0].role);
    };
    fetchData();
  }, [setRows, userID, token]);
```

Example input field:

```
<input
 type="text"
 className="form-control"
 id="inputEmail4"
 placeholder="First Name"
 name="firstName"
 value={firstName}
 onChange={(e) => setFirstName(e.target.value)}
></input>
```

By doing it this way, the form maps through "rows", and then each input field immediately gets a new state once typing occurs.

I know it's ugly, but it is effective. I'm new to coding so I don't know all the ins and outs of React yet - but this solution works for me. Hope this helps anyone looking for a solution to the same issue!