# pre-populate form from API in React front-end

Tags: reactjs, forms, cookies

I am learning React by building a front end to a remote REST API. (I can modify the remote API if needed.) So far, I have a function on the front end like this:

```
function FooForm() {

const [inputs, setInputs] = useState({});

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    const name = event.target.name;
    const value = event.target.value;
    setInputs(values => ({...values, [name]: value}))
  }

  const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    // Here is where I'd post to the API
  }

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <label>Foo
        <input 
          type="text" 
          name="foo" 
          value={inputs.foo || ""} 
          onChange={handleChange}
        />
      </label>
      <br />
      <label>Bar
        <input 
          type="text" 
          name="bar" 
          value={inputs.bar || ""} 
          onChange={handleChange}
        />
      </label>
      <br />
      <input type="submit" />
    </form>
  )
}
```

It will POST to an API endpoint. But how can I manipulate the form so that the text fields are pre-loaded with values from the database, e.g. something like `value={inputs.foo || preload.foo}`, and so on?

This [poster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73999130/edit-form-that-is-pre-filled-with-api-data-react) answered his own question by opting to use the `useEffect` hook in a certain way, but it is unclear from the context how React/fetch deals with cookies. Does that happen automatically? Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

```
function FooForm() {
  const [inputs, setInputs] = useState({});

+ const init = () => {
+   fetch(/* some setting */).then(res=>setInputs(values => ({...res.data})))
+ }

+ useEffect(()=>{
+   init()
+ },[])

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    const name = event.target.name;
    const value = event.target.value;
    setInputs(values => ({...values, [name]: value}))
  }

  const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    // Here is where I'd post to the API
  }

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <label>Foo
        <input 
          type="text" 
          name="foo" 
          value={inputs.foo || ""} 
          onChange={handleChange}
        />
      </label>
      <br />
      <label>Bar
        <input 
          type="text" 
          name="bar" 
          value={inputs.bar || ""} 
          onChange={handleChange}
        />
      </label>
      <br />
      <input type="submit" />
    </form>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A few things, the best practice is for your `input`'s `value` to have the initial value of the state `inputs` which in your case is an object with properties `foo` and `bar` instead of using `||` operator.

Then to include *cookies* in your HTTP request it's nothing related to React but rather the library you are using to make those HTTP request.

Let's say you use [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#sending_a_request_with_credentials_included) and their way is to include an optional object with a key-value of: `credentials: 'include'`.

And no you actually wouldn't need `useEffect` hook in this case since you are just `POST`ing a request, the `useEffect` is required only if you were to receive the data in the same component, which I don't see that you are doing that in your current code, but I can add some example since you mentioned that.

```js
function FooForm() {

  const [inputs, setInputs] = useState({
   //initial input values
   foo: "",
   bar: ""
  });

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    const name = event.target.name;
    const value = event.target.value;
    setInputs(values => ({...values, [name]: value}))
  }

//Initialize a state for the expected data
  const [dataReceived, setDataReceived] = useState("");

  const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    // Here is where I'd post to the API

    // Let's say you are using 'fetch':
    fetch('https://myapi.com', {
     //optional property to include credentials(cookies, etc.)
     method: 'POST',
     credentials: 'include'
     //...the rest of your code here
    }).then(res => res.json()).then(data => {
     setDataReceived(data);
    })
  }

  // For useEffect use-case let's say you are expecting to 
  // receive some data after the component renders
  useEffect(() => {

   const fetchNewData = () => { 
    fetch('https://myapi.com', {
     method: 'GET',
     credentials: 'include'
    }).then(res => res.json()).then(data => {
     setDataReceived(data);
    })
   };
   fetchNewData();

  // Empty dependency array meaning it only runs
  // when the component mounts. If you wish
  // it to re-run when different state changes
  // then add that state in the dependency array
  },[])

  return (
   <div>
    <p>My received data: {dataReceived}</p>
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <label>Foo
        <input 
          type="text" 
          name="foo" 
          value={inputs.foo} 
          onChange={handleChange}
        />
      </label>
      <br />
      <label>Bar
        <input 
          type="text" 
          name="bar" 
          value={inputs.bar} 
          onChange={handleChange}
        />
      </label>
      <br />
      <input type="submit" />
    </form>
   </div>
  )
}
```

---

An extra tip: if you were to use a `button` element inside your `form` it has, by default, a `type="submit"` so you don't have to explicitly code it, but it's still a best practice to include it.